# AWS VPC Endpoints setting to S3 and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, endpoint, amazon-vpc

Amazon RDS is set to use VPC.

I am trying to configure a VPC Endpoint for an ETL job.

When I looked at the documentation to set up the VPC Endpoint, I got this:

> The source IPv4 addresses from instances in your affected subnets as received by Amazon S3 change from public IPv4 addresses to the private IPv4 addresses from your VPC. An endpoint switches network routes, and disconnects open TCP connections. Your tasks are interrupted during the changeover, and any previous connections using public IPv4 addresses are not resumed. We recommend that you do not have any critical tasks running when you create or modify an endpoint; or that you test to ensure that your software can automatically reconnect to Amazon S3 after the connection break.

EC2 service logs S3, and Lambda logs s3. But I don't know how to test.

How to test if there is no problem when setting VPC?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Can you edit your question to better explain what you are asking? Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I want to set up an AWS VPC endpoint. By the way, the warning is written in the AWS documentation as above. If the connection is lost, try testing to see if it reconnects, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your actual question? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)